# Linter can't read the property of $('.add-circle')/undefined using MatterJS lib

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm trying create new shapes that drop down into the canvas when you press the button for that shape. I'm using a CDN. Only two pages are my index and app.js. My canvas appears along with the buttons and the first ball drops down but whenever I press the button nothing happens. The console says "$" is undefined. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, on my index page my CDN is in a script tag and comes before my app.js script tag.

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

var engine = Engine.create();

var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    wireframes: false
  }
});

var topWall = Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 810, 30, { isStatic: true });
var leftWall = Bodies.rectangle(0, 200, 30, 420, { isStatic: true });
var ball = Bodies.circle(460, 10, 40, 10);
var bottomWall = Bodies.rectangle(400, 400, 810, 30, { isStatic: true });

World.add(engine.world, [topWall, leftWall, ball, bottomWall]);

Engine.run(engine);

Render.run(render);


var addCircle = function () {
  return Bodies.circle(Math.random() * 400 + 30, 30, 30);
};

var addSquare = function () {
  return Bodies.rectangle(Math.random() * 400 + 30, 30, 60, 60);
};

var addRect = function () {
  return Bodies.rectangle(Math.random() * 400 + 30, 30, 100, 60);
};
```

This is where my issue is. I followed the tutorial as well.

```
$('.add-circle').on('click', function () {
  World.add(engine.world, addCircle());
});

$('.add-square').on('click', function () {
  World.add(engine.world, addSquare());
})

$('.add-rect').on('click', function () {
  World.add(engine.world, addRect());
})
```

Comment: Did you add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to import jQuery before all of your scripts? Please show a [mcve]